# UI getting overlapped by game Tiles how to fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, sprite, 2d-games

My UI for my score is getting overwritten by the sprites of the tiles of my game(Unity 2D). (when the UI interferes with ground tiles it goes underneath the tiles and doesnt show above it.) For the rest my Text is working fine and my code gives no errors but this problem has been hard to fix for me. Does anyone know how to set f.e priorities for UI and or sprites?

Thanks in advance,

TAZ

Answer (score 0):

Maker sure to create a Canvas and put all of your UI as a child of it.
Under Canvas you can set the sorting layer to Foreground 9999999 which will overwrite everything less than that sorting layer
Also check the Z-Axis